# Improperly functioning Nav

Tags: html, css, nav

Like many before me, I am relatively new to HTML & CSS and I have hit a wall!
I downloaded a template that had a nav but I went ahead and put in my own fixed nav. 
I have several sections on my site and the issue I am having is the nav only works when you scroll midway down through the second section! It works perfect from then on but not in the first section!

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <a href="#header">Home</a>
        <a href="#one">About Me</a>
        <a href="#two">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#three">Contact</a>
        <a href="#four">Links</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {  /* added for fixed navbar*/
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Kevin

Comment: [z-index Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Rather than use z-index, you can also simply ensure that your nav is near the top of your html code. It's good practice to arrange elements in your html the way you want them to look on your page where possible.

Comment: move your nav just after `<body>` tag